# Setting time with date and hwclock does not permanently set the time

Tags: 18.04, time

I'm running these:

```
~$ sudo date --set="2021-06-09 16:33:50.0"
Wed Jun  9 16:33:50 UTC 2021
~$ sudo hwclock --systohc
```

once the system is rebooted it loses the info and its 4 hours off.

This is an offline system and there is no ntp or chrony solution that will work.

Comment: Does this computer dual boot Ubuntu and Windows?

Comment: No its just Ubuntu

Comment: Change the hwclock button battery? Look for time setting in `sudo journalctl  -b 0`. Read `man timedatectl`.